# How do I get this kind of YouTube page?

Tags: youtube

I have a client that wants his YouTube channel page to be designed this way:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/insanehomefatloss
```

The problem is that I cannot alter the content ABOVE the video. Obviously there is some HTML/CSS setting that I cannot access in entirety and I would like to be able to edit that part.

Any ideas, info?

BTW, the client has the partner status on youtube, his channel is:
http://www.youtube.com/user/chainfitness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is their background image. you can find it [here](http://i4.ytimg.com/u/G4gi0PrPer_JlYBi9lAsOQ/channels3_background.jpg?v=4fad624c): 2946 pixels wide by 1490 pixes high.

How you get the link at the top to work: Go into [Channel Settings](http://www.youtube.com/channel_editor?action_editor=1&editor_tab=branding) and upload the background image that you want.

Youtube partners are allowed to have a custom header/link in their channels. Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18j7W20V_1M) that shows you how to add a banner/link to the top of your youtube partner channel. It's kind of a goofy video, but it's helpful